# Only link third party framework on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

I'm using a third party Objective-C framework in my project. This framework is only supported on devices, but not the simulator. How can I still compile my project for the simulator and just not use that framework, to be able to test the rest of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your framework with macro `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`. Something like:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    //  do not import the framework
#else
    //  import the framework and use it
#endif
```

EDIT:

You can optionally link the framework/library by settings given below:

- If the third-party is a library (a file with extension `.a`), then use this:

  [image: Linking a library]

  and make sure path for your library is included in the `Library Search Paths` for related configuration.
- If it is a framework (a folder with extension `.framework`), then use this:

  [image: Linking a framework]

  and make sure path for your framework is included in the `Framework Search Paths` for related configuration.

Comment: Thanks. And how can I link it only when compiling for the simulator?